Requires Babel "^7.16.0", but was loaded with "7.12.3"
I have a react js application running in React 17 with Node 14 version. And it is legacy application on react-scripts version "4.0.3". Everything was fine until Aug 08 when the npm build started to fail with the following error:

Requires Babel "^7.16.0", but was loaded with "7.12.3".
If you are sure you have a compatible version of u/babel/core,
it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version.
Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that
doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.
(While processing: "node_modules\babel-pre set-react-app\index.js$0$2")

On same day I saw couple of posts over internet like the below one:
https://dev.to/jitendra_singh_428933c91c/babel-7160-but-was-loaded-with-7123-1iaa. But there are no proper solutions attached to it. Any help is much appreciated.
I am trying to build my react application using npm run build with inbuild webpacks of react-scripts.

Resolved with downgrading caniuse-lite as babel had upgraded to latest versions.
"caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632"
npm install caniuse-lite@1.0.30001632 --save

yarn add caniuse-lite@1.0.30001632

Place the following in package.json depending on what you use yarn or npm for installation.
For npm
  "overrides": {
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632"
  },


For yarn
  "resolutions": {
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632"
  },


The above solution worked, thanks for sharing. Could you explain how you identified the specific package causing the compatibility issue?

This PR helped me understand.
https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/16614/files

This + answer by @gokhankaraoglu solved my problem

I encountered this error in my react project pipeline. It was fixed only when I installed the @babel/core package.
node version: 14
npm install --save-dev @babel/core


I have installed @babel/core ver. 7.16.0 with this command and work 'npm install @babel/core@7.16.0 --save'

Using Yarn 3.x btw.
Ditch CRA
Obviously upgrading react-scripts to 5.x.x or moving off of Create React App completely helps, but from my experience, both options require significant time and sanity investment. If you choose to do it, I'd recommend ditching CRA. It's no longer maintained.
Incompatible @babel/* dependencies in monorepo
I'm maintaining a large monorepo and the first issue related to this was CRA's babel-loader not being able to parse never language features (optional chaining, nullish coalescing, etc.). The error was "Unexpected token ...". It was due to one of our workspaces installing a never version of @babel/core, which caused a ton of internally incompatible resolutions in yarn.lock.
The solution was to manually delete all @babel/* entries from yarn.lock and running yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn dedupe to let Yarn regenerate those with the latest applicable version and hopefully compatible manner. This helped the parsing issue, but a new issue that's mentioned by OP popped up.
"Requires Babel 7.16.0 ..."
Yeah, ultimately what helped was using resolutions to force downgrade caniuse-lite to 1.0.30001632 (thx @Geeek).

I also was facing similar issue and after a lot of research found out the solution
Changing browser targets from
"browserslist": {
   "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
},

to
"browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
], 

more details here - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642
but while implementing this solution also I faced another issue https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/266, I fixed this issue by adding following to .browserlistrc
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not ie <= 10
not ie_mob <= 10
not bb <= 10
not op_mob <= 12.1


I had to use a combination of @Greek's answer with another modification.
npm install caniuse-lite@1.0.30001632 --save
npm install babel-preset-react-app@10.0.0 --save

And then update my package.json with
  "overrides": {
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.0"
  }


Upgrade react-scripts from 4.0.3 -> 5.0.1
